# npm install --global expo-cli will not install on my Mac

Tags: reactjs, npm, expo

I'm having some trouble installing the exp cli on my computer. I currently have node -v 16.13.1. I ran `npm install --global expo-cli` and got a lot of error codes that seem to relate to permission issues. So then I ran `sudo npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm`, and still had no luck. Any idea?

> npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been
> deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will
> no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped
> packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and
> etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package
> you should use instead

Comment: use ``sudo`` before the command

Comment: please, attach your error in your question.